# How to get specific value from JSON array using C#

Tags: c#, json

I need help trying to extract "RiskID" value from the attached JSON using C# and Newtonsoft.

The response is JSON array and that is why I'm having some difficulty.

I tried to do some testing using below code but it is not working

```
JArray jArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonstring);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    JArray jArray1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jArray[i].ToString());
                    string key = ((JValue)jArray1[0]).Value == null ? "" : ((JValue)jArray1[0]).Value.ToString();
                    string value = ((JValue)jArray1[1]).Value == null ? "" : ((JValue)jArray1[1]).Value.ToString();
                    Response.Write(key + " : " + value +"<br>");
                }
```

Thanks for your help.

```
[
    {
        "Bur": {
            "RiskSummary": {
                "Address": {
                    "StreetAddress1": "423 W OLYMPIC BLVD",
                    "City": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "PostalCity": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "State": "CA",
                    "Zip": "90640",
                    "Zip4": "5225",
                    "County": "LOS ANGELES"
                },
                "FPA": "MONTEBELLO",
                "RiskId": "64CX99016399",
                "OnsiteSurveyDate": "05/01/1999",
                "ScheduleAppliedDate": "04/21/1999",
                "YearBuilt": "1960"
            },
            "Comments": {
                "GeneralComments": [],
                "WindComments": "",
                "WindLossHistory": ""
            }
        },
        "Pdr": null,
        "Bov": null,
        "ReportCode": "BUR"
    },
    {
        "Bur": {"RiskSummary": {
                "Address": {
                    "StreetAddress1": "423 W OLYMPIC BLVD",
                    "City": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "PostalCity": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "State": "CA",
                    "Zip": "90640",
                    "Zip4": "5225",
                    "County": "LOS ANGELES"
                },
                "FPA": "MONTEBELLO",
                "RiskId": "64CX99012345",
                "OnsiteSurveyDate": "05/01/1999",
                "ScheduleAppliedDate": "04/21/1999",
                "YearBuilt": "1960"
            },
            "Comments": {
                "GeneralComments": [],
                "WindComments": "",
                "WindLossHistory": ""
            }
        },
        "Pdr": null,
        "Bov": null,
        "ReportCode": "BUR"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please provide more details than "it is not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to parse your json string to json array

```
    string[] riskIds = JArray.Parse(jsonstring)
                             .Select(a => a.SelectToken("Bur.RiskSummary.RiskId").Value<string>())
                             .ToArray();
                             
    string  riskId0 = riskIds[0];            
    string  riskId1 = riskIds[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to get the value you want.

```
JArray jArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonstring);

string[] valueArray = jArray.Select(p => p["Bur"]["RiskSummary"["RiskId"].ToString()).ToArray();

string value = string.Join(":", valueArray);`
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**